# Have a link in custom crm report

Tags: sdk, report, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Is it possible to have a link in a custom crm report?

In the picture, How can I make patientId as link that when it is clicked, the patient form opens?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn those labels into hyperlinks, [seems to be plenty of questions on this already](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=ssrs%20hyperlink).

Use this information to set the correct URL to open the patient form

[Open forms, views, dialogs and reports with a URL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328483.aspx), for example:

`http://myorg.crm.dynamics.com/main.aspx?etn=[your entity name goes here]&pagetype=entityrecord&id=[record Id goes here]`

Comment: Thanks friend.
That was a good hint to find the answer.
@James Wood


   `="http://myorg.crm.dynamics.com/main.aspx?etn=[your entity name        goes here]&pagetype=entityrecord&id" &      Fields!bartar_newpaitientid.Value.ToString()
   `